# MSE and log-MSE after applying log transformation

Tags: forecasting, data-transformation, loss-functions

Consider a time series $\{Y\}$ and the forecast $\hat{Y}_{t+1}$ for the true value $Y_{t+1}$.
Now consider the time series $\{y\}$, where $y_t \equiv log(Y_t)$, and the forecast $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ for the true value $y_{t+1}$.
Are the functions $L_1(Y_{t+1}, \hat{Y}_{t+1}) = (logY_{t+1} -log\hat{Y}_{t+1})^2$ and $L_2(y_{t+1}, \hat{y}_{t+1}) = (y_{t+1} - \hat{y}_{t+1})^2$ the same? If not, is there any way to obtain the value of $\hat{Y}_{t+1}$ assuming to know $\hat{y}_{t+1}$?

Comment: Are you calculating two *separate* forecasts $\hat{Y}$ and $\hat{y}$? If so, then there can be pretty much no connection between the two (and therefore also not between the two loss functions): because of the logging, your forecasting algorithm might, e.g., select a seasonal model for the original series and a non-seasonal model for the logged series. Or the other way around. ...

Comment: ... What one usually does is to log-transform the original series, model and forecast this logged series, obtain a point forecast, then transform that one back. Note that the back-transformation will usually require a bias correction for an expectation forecast, see the bottom of [this page](https://otexts.com/fpp3/ftransformations.html).